# Transform key to pairs on condition?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an generic object and object which determines pair keys:

```js
const obj = {
   key1: 1,
   key2: 2,
   key3: 3,
};

const pairs = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
};
```

Resulting object in this case would be:

```js
const result = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
  key2: 2
};
```

Pairs have more precedence if both keys in pair is present in source object then pair with value is taken, else single key/val is taken. E.g. another scenario:

```js
const obj = {
   key1: 1,
   key2: 2,
   key4: 3,
};

const pairs = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
};

const result = {
   key1: 1,
   key2: 2,
   key4: 3,
};

// same as obj, because no key1 and key3 is present
```

How can i achieve these logic with lodash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reduce the `pairs` object and initial `obj` into a new object:

```js
const obj = {
   key1: 1,
   key2: 2,
   key4: 3,
};

const pairs = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
};

let result = Object.keys(pairs).reduce((carr, curr) => {
   if (typeof curr === 'string') {
      let needles = curr.split(':')
      
      if (needles.every(k => Object.keys(obj).includes(k))) {
         needles.forEach(n => {
            delete carr[n]
         })
         
         return Object.assign(carr, { [curr]: pairs[curr] })
      }
   }
   
   return carr
}, Object.assign({}, { ...obj }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not complete, but you can extend this logic to solve your issue.

```js
/** const obj = {
   key1: 1,
   key2: 2,
   key4: 3,
};

const pairs = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
};
**/

const obj = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3,
};

const pairs = {
  'key1:key3': 666,
};

const pairKeys = Object.keys(pairs);

pairKeys.forEach((key) => {
  const keys = key.split(':');
  const isAllKeysPresent = keys.every(k => {
    return !!obj[k]; // returns boolean
  });

  const objCopy = { ...obj
  };
  if (isAllKeysPresent) {
    keys.forEach(k => {
      delete objCopy[k];
    })

    console.log({ ...pairs,
      ...objCopy
    })
  } else {
    console.log(objCopy)
  }
})
```